# Cannot read property constructor of undefined, Redux, React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, native

Im configuring Redux in my React Native project. Unfortunately, I get a problem "Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined" connected to, I guess, createEpicMiddleware(). Do you have any idea what might cause the problem? Thx!

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose }       from 'redux';
import { default as OneReducer } from './One';
import { default as TwoReducer } from './Two';
import { navReducer } from './Navigation';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { combineEpics, createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-  observable';
import { epics as OneEpics } from './One/epics';
import { epics as TwoEpics } from './Two/epics';
import { middleware as navMiddleware } from "../navigation";

const enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(createLogger())
);

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    one: OneReducer,
    two: TwoReducer,
});

const rootEpic = combineEpics(
    OneEpics,
    TwoEpics
);

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

const store = createStore(rootReducer,    applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware, navMiddleware));
epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
```

Comment: That error message should come with the source code line. Which line is the error referring to?

Comment: createEpicMiddleware.js:23:44

Comment: Thanks but what is on that line?

Comment: After deleting and nom install node modules, there is a little bit different alert: "undefined is not an object evaluating rxjs queueScheduler.constructor" in createEpicMiddleware, redux-logger.js:1:5017. It will be difficult to paste the whole line :/

Comment: how can you fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you the error is here because installed version of `rxjs` does not match with one which should be used with `redux-observable`

Updatting rxjs to `">=6.0.0-beta.0 <7"` should fix the issue